# Another way to get multiple elements in React with intersection observer

Tags: reactjs

I need to get multiple nodes. I've tried using `document.querySelectorAll(...)` (see below), but I'm not sure if this approach is viable in React, without messing with the React backend too much. Is there a better way to do this? (Another option I've thought of is making a manual list of refs, but I don't want to do that if I don't have to.)

```
useEffect(() => {
  const hiddenElements =
    document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          entry.target.classList.add('show')
        }
      })
    },
    {threshold: 0}
  )

  hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el))
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, the best approach is simply not to do that. Instead, you would put the IntersectionObserver-related logic inside your entry component. That way, you don't need to touch the DOM node outside of that component, and you can update the class-list by updating that component's state (and passing that to the DOM node in the normal React way). And you don't have to worry that the list of nodes will become out of date due to some nested component re-rendering.

> Another option I've thought of is making a manual list of refs, but I don't want to do that if I don't have to.

If, for whatever reason, you find that you really do need an ancestor component to have a list of various DOM nodes belonging to descendant components, then I think the best approach is for the ancestor component to define a callback method to be called when a relevant DOM node is created/replaced/removed, and to pass that callback down to the relevant descendants (either as properties or by using [context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)). The relevant descendants can then use a [ref callback](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback) to invoke the ancestor's callback whenever appropriate.

That might look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const OnUpdateRelevantNodeContext = createContext(null);

export function App(props) {
  const [relevantNodes, setRelevantNodes] = useState([]);

  const onUpdateRelevantNode = useCallback((oldNode, newNode) => {
    console.log('Replacing ' + oldNode + ' with ' + newNode + ' . . .')
    setRelevantNodes(oldRelevantNodes => {
      const newRelevantNodes = oldRelevantNodes.slice();
      const indexToRemove = newRelevantNodes.indexOf(oldNode);
      if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
        newRelevantNodes.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
      }
      if (newNode !== null && newRelevantNodes.indexOf(newNode) === -1) {
        newRelevantNodes.push(newNode);
      }
      return newRelevantNodes
    })
  }, [setRelevantNodes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('relevantNodes: [' + relevantNodes.map(node => node.innerHTML).join(', ') + ']')
  }, [relevantNodes])

  return (
    <OnUpdateRelevantNodeContext.Provider value={onUpdateRelevantNode}>
      <RelevantDescendant>
        first
      </RelevantDescendant>
      <RelevantDescendant>
        second
      </RelevantDescendant>
    </OnUpdateRelevantNodeContext.Provider>
  );
}

const RelevantDescendant = (props) => {
  const onUpdateNode = useContext(OnUpdateRelevantNodeContext);

  const oldNodeRef = useRef(null);

  const refCallback = useCallback(newNode => {
    onUpdateNode(oldNodeRef.current, newNode);
    oldNodeRef.current = newNode;
  }, [onUpdateNode]);

  return <div {...props} ref={refCallback} />;
};
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the code above, but I'll mark the answer as accepted since you know what you are talking about